# android flash turn on/off using button while camera is running

Tags: android, camera, flashlight

I saw that there are many questions liek this but I didn't find any way. In my app I have my own Camera with some options , and also have button named `btnFlash` for turning on/off camera's flash light while camera is running. I tried many ways, but nothing worked as on Samsung tab and HTC. here is one of them

```
ImageButton btnFlash = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_flash);
        btnFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                if( context .getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(getPackageManager().FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                    Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    if(isFlashOn) {
                        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                        isFlashOn = false;
                    } else {
                        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                        mCamera.setParameters(params);
                        isFlashOn = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

1. Can anyone suggest some good tutorial or some code?
2. Can same code work on e.g. HTC but not work on samsung? I mean can I wrote some code for any type of android device?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: flash is having problems many time. You have to use surface view to on/off flash. Then it will work as charm.

Comment: surface View? but how? I have one surface View , and on it is my camera's video, can you please tell me more details? thank you very much, and please leave your comment as an answer if you can give more details

Comment: Please see answer posted by me below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this link. This helps me to achieve flash functionality in almost all devices.

Import this SVN project.

http://code.google.com/p/torch/source/checkout

Comment: @HaykNahapetyan Just go through this answer.

Comment: @Rahil2952 please check this issue, same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276908/flash-not-working-while-custom-camera-is-running

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you and I think you should replace

```
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

with this

```
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

I tested the param

```
    Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON
    Parameters.FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE
```

and had the same problem, I think the problem occur because the device does not have appropriate hardware parametes